# 2PC Private Set Intersection Optimized for asymmetrically sized sets

Tags: multiparty-computation, private-set-intersection

I am researching some concepts of practical 2 party computation and was curious if anyone could point me to a research paper that is focused on private set intersection where one party has a very large set and the other has a comparatively small set.  Specifically, a user has a small set and the server has a large set.  Since the server will handle thousands or millions of requests, I am more concerned about the performance for the server.

The specific use case that I had in mind is contact discovery.  Meaning, a user wants to know who else is using a service but does not want to disclose their contacts to the server in plain text.  Ideally the server does not learn the outcome of the intersection.  At a minimum the server should only learn the size of the users contact list and the results of the intersection.

I found this [paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/515.pdf) that appears to be a breakthrough in performance but it's benchmarks are based on two sets of equal size.  Is there existing research on a PSI that is optimized for non-equal set size?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to observe that any secure protocol must touch every bit of both parties' inputs -- otherwise it's not secure.

However recent work has shown that you can *amortize* the protocol complexity over several runs, with state stored between the runs, so that not every execution will touch every bit.   See [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/oram.pdf) for the paper.  It doesn't address set intersection directly, but since it covers a generic function it applies to your case.